# Chartjs Tooltip Line Breaks

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Is it possible to get line breaks in chartjs tooltips?

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>"
```

I want to replace ": " with a new line.

I've tried with `&#013;`, `\u000D`, `\n` and `<br />` to no avail.

**Update:** I have changed my accepted answer now that [`chart.js`](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js) is on version 2.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you are using 2.0.0-beta2, you can use tooltip callback and return array of strings there.

```js
tooltips: {
    mode: 'single',
    callbacks: {
        afterBody: function(data) {
            var multistringText = ['first string'];
            // do some stuff
            multistringText.push('another string');

            return multistringText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working as of 11/1/2016 and should be the accepted answer for linebreaks in tooltips if using chartjs 2. (or angular charts).

Comment: any Idea on this question @AlexyPavlov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65586632/chartjs-with-angular-position-tooltip-carret-above-and-middle-of-bar

Answer (score 30):

Actually all tool-tip callbacks support multiple lines of text, and you can use `label` callback as usual. It renders data label as tool-tip text by default.

Quoted from [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks):

> All functions must return either a string or an array of strings. Arrays of strings are treated as multiple lines of text.

Example code:

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
        if (tooltipItem.index % 2)
          return ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
        else
          return 'Single line';
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Great answer my friend. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 12):

You can use tooltips footer callback,it will also not render coloured square for each list.

```html
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      let label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label;
      let value = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
      return label + ': ' + value;
    },
    footer: function(tooltipItems, data) {
      return ['new line', 'another line'];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

At this point in time, it's not possible to add line breaks to a tooltip or axis label. Right now the developers are discussion implementation options; the discussion can be found [Allow wrapping in axis labels (issue on github)](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/608).

Comment: For any googlers, it's worth checking out that github link; there are some suggestions on it (so possibly a solution for you).

Comment: I believe this was implemented in v2 https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/2704

Comment: Its implemented, instead of adding <br> or \n\r you have to put each line in a returned array form.

Comment: Also bullets appear in front of every line. It seems more like a workaround.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. Just simply return an array of strings as labels in tooltips.

```
 tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        let label = "Line 1";
        let label2 = "Line 2";
        return [label, label2];
      }
    }
  }
```