# Chartjs multiple line tooltip with color boxes for each line

Tags: chart.js

How to add color box on chartjs multiline tooltip?

[image]

What I did for multiple line is:

```
    mode: 'single',
    callbacks: {
        afterBody: function(data) {
            var multistringText = ['first string'];
            // do some stuff
            multistringText.push('another string');

            return multistringText;
        }
    }
}

But I wanted a color box along with the multiple text with different color on them.
The code is from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302392/chartjs-tooltip-line-breaks
```

Comment: can you add a picture to understand easily what you want?

Comment: @ThoVo I have added a picture of what I want it to be like.

Comment: you can do it with a custom tooltip, inside tooltip, create a div for different kind of data and style it globally, just put your tooltip class under a specific class