# How can I automatically wrap tooltip text content to multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm using [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/) to generate some charts. The data point tooltips are generated using callbacks via the configurations option:

```js
tooltips: {
    position: 'average',
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
    callbacks: {
        title: tooltipTitleCallback,
        label: tooltipLabelCallback
    }
},
```

The callbacks return a string of varying length. My problem is that ChartJS doesn't seem to provide any way to automatically wrap the text to multiple lines (similar to a Bootstrap tooltip). Instead, any text that doesn't fit on 1 line is truncated.

[image: truncated tooltip]

It does allow the callback to [return an array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35442835/1264804) which it will separate by line break. Currently the only workaround I can think of is to measure the length of each tooltip and split the text into an array if it's sufficiently long (not responsive or ideal). I'd rather not re-make the wheel if there's a simple solution to this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chartjs Tooltip Line Breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302392/chartjs-tooltip-line-breaks)

Comment: @DanielBeck No. That question is already linked in my question and doesn't provide a way to 'automatically wrap text to multiple lines'

Comment: Right, sorry about that. Didn't spot you'd already linked it, my bad

Comment: @DanielBeck No worries, thanks for retracting the close vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A solution for ChartJS 2.0. We can provide a function to build a HTML tooltip**.

[Here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#external-custom-tooltips) are some examples of using custom [tooltips](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/).

We turn off canvas tooltips.

`enabled: false`

We use the tooltips opacity state to show or hide our custom tooltip. The state is updated when a `hover` event is triggered.

Our `tooltipTitleCallback` and `tooltipLabelCallback` functions will need to be modified depending on the parameters we're passing in. In this example, we're using the tooltip's [`dataPoints`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-interface) property in our `tooltipTitleCallback` function. The items which are available in the data property is determined by the [interaction mode](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html) used.

[Here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-model) are some other properties in the tooltip model.

To prevent the tooltip from going over the right hand side of the screen, we set the `right` position property instead of the `left`.

**Working example**

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const customTooltip = {
  mode: "index",
  enabled: false,
  custom: function(model) {
    const tooltip = document.getElementById("tooltip");

    if (model.opacity === 0) {
      tooltip.style.opacity = 0;
      return;
    }

    if (model.body) {
      const title = "<strong>" + tooltipTitleCallback(model.dataPoints) + "</strong>";
      const label =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros non massa consequat, ac. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros non massa consequat, ac. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pellentesque eros non massa consequat, ac.";

      tooltip.innerHTML = title + "<br />" + label;

      tooltip.style.left = "auto";
      tooltip.style.right = "auto";

      const pos = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (model.xAlign === "left") {
        tooltip.style.left = pos.left + model.caretX + "px";
      } else {
        tooltip.style.right = pos.right - model.caretX + "px";
      }

      tooltip.style.top = -50 + pos.top + model.caretY + "px";
      tooltip.style.opacity = 1;
    }
  }
};

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: customTooltip
  }
});

function tooltipTitleCallback(items) {
  if (items.length > 0) {
    const item = items[0];

    if (item.label) {
      return item.label;
    }

    return "No title";
  }
}
```

```css
#tooltip {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease;
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 15px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<div id="tooltip"></div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/CraftedPod/pen/abZgyzm)

Comment: This is more of a workaround about how to create your own tooltips. As Chartjs is an open source project, it would be better if we were to contribute improvements to the existing code rather than just working around it. Clearly it's not working for everyone.

Comment: @Webber Fair point - our experiences with the software can help ChartJS improve the code for everybody. There are [community guidelines](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/contributing) we need to follow when contributing fixes and new features. The above is a solution for the original poster to consider when factoring in time constraints and language and framework experience. The documentation does say: "Custom tooltips allow you to hook into the tooltip rendering process so that you can render the tooltip in your own custom way."

Comment: Yea fair enough. I was more expecting an answer in the form of changing the width of the tooltip, as it is cut off; or an answer mentioning how putting that many words in a tooltip is not really good practice as there are better ways of presenting information too.